# django migrations not working after database renaming

Tags: django, database-migration

I am following a tutorial and decided to rename the default database from db.sqlite3 to db.tictactoe. I have added a couple of models and run the migrations with the command makemigrations:

[image]

The migrations run with no erros but the table are not created inside the db.tictactoe database. The file db.sqlite3 is recreated instead:

[image]

Here my settings.py:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: while deleting Database delete `migrations` folders as well

Comment: Settings are only loaded on server start. Did you restart your sever after renaming the DB?